# SQL - advice on grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

SQL Server 2005. I am **not** after a coded answer here (although it would be nice). I'm really after advice on the best way forward to get the result I need. I have some knowledge of pivot/unpivot/cte//rownumber and dynamic queries but cannot get my head around this particular problem! An example of the data follows. **Note:** The occurrence of type,location,name and description can be none to many.

```
drop table #temp
create table #temp
(
event int,
type varchar(20),
locations varchar(20),
name varchar(30),
description varchar(50)
)
insert into #temp values (1,'support','r1','fred','desc 1')
insert into #temp values (1,'support','r1','fred','desc 2')
insert into #temp values (1,'support','r1','fred','desc 3')

insert into #temp values (1,'support','r1','jim','desc 1')
insert into #temp values (1,'support','r1','jim','desc 2')
insert into #temp values (1,'support','r1','jim','desc 3')

insert into #temp values (1,'support','r2','fred','desc 1')
insert into #temp values (1,'support','r2','fred','desc 2')
insert into #temp values (1,'support','r2','fred','desc 3')

insert into #temp values (1,'support','r2','jim','desc 1')
insert into #temp values (1,'support','r2','jim','desc 2')
insert into #temp values (1,'support','r2','jim','desc 3')

insert into #temp values (1,'work','r1','fred','desc 1')
insert into #temp values (1,'work','r1','fred','desc 2')
insert into #temp values (1,'work','r1','fred','desc 3')

insert into #temp values (1,'work','r1','jim','desc 1')
insert into #temp values (1,'work','r1','jim','desc 2')
insert into #temp values (1,'work','r1','jim','desc 3')

insert into #temp values (1,'work','r2','fred','desc 1')
insert into #temp values (1,'work','r2','fred','desc 2')
insert into #temp values (1,'work','r2','fred','desc 3')

insert into #temp values (1,'work','r2','jim','desc 1')
insert into #temp values (1,'work','r2','jim','desc 2')
insert into #temp values (1,'work','r2','jim','desc 3')

select * from #temp
```

The result I am after is this ..

```
1,support;work,r1;r2,fred;jim,desc1;desc2;desc3
```

Comment: you want to return a single string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal seem to select all distinct value of all columns, then Concatenate into one string. And you only need advice, so I recommend you go here: [multiple rows into a single row](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/)

It seem that you need more help:

```
select distinct
stuff((SELECT distinct'; ' + type-- as type
        FROM #temp 
        --order by type
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
+ (SELECT distinct'; ' + locations
        FROM #temp 
        FOR XML PATH(''))
+ (SELECT distinct'; ' + name
        FROM #temp 
        FOR XML PATH(''))
+ (SELECT distinct'; ' + description 
        FROM #temp 
        FOR XML PATH(''))
 from #temp;
```

If you need 4 columns, then change `+ (SELECT` to `, stuff((SELECT`

The query is just that simple: get distinct of one column, change into string, then concatenate + string of (next column)...

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly unrelated, but when inserting data like this it would be easier (for you) to do it like this (also, try to get into the habit of naming the fields you are inserting into);

```
INSERT INTO #temp (event, type, locations, name, description)
VALUES (1,'support','r1','fred','desc 1')
,(1,'support','r1','fred','desc 2')
,(1,'support','r1','fred','desc 3')
,(1,'support','r1','jim','desc 1')
,(1,'support','r1','jim','desc 2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't up-vote this version! All up-votes should go to the solution above! The code below is simply for completeness. This shows the syntax for organising the data into separate columns based on the answer from @NayruLove

```
SELECT  distinct x.event,
stuff((SELECT distinct'; ' + t.type 
     FROM #temp t 
    where t.event = x.event  
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as type
, stuff((SELECT distinct'; ' + locations
    FROM #temp t
    where t.event= x.event
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as room
, stuff((SELECT distinct'; ' + name
    FROM #temp t
    where t.event = x.event
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as name
, stuff((SELECT distinct'; ' + description 
    FROM #temp t
    where t.event = x.event
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as description
 from #temp x
group by x.event
```

Comment: Thks, and one more note: if you need ordering, then remove all comment in query for example of column `type`

Comment: Hi @NayruLove. Thanks! However I am having problems when applying this to multiple records. So a similar pattern is repeated for Event=2, Event = 3, Event = 4 etc.

Comment: Continuing the above comment .. What I'm getting is a concatenation of all types, all locations, all names and all descriptions. What I'm really after is to have these concatenations connected with a particular key e.g. `key = 1,support;work,r1;r2,fred;jim,desc1;desc2;desc3             key = 2,this;that,r6;r7,mik;ian,desc10;desc21;desc13` etc

Comment: Then you should research more at the original link I have recommend: [multiple rows into a single row](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/). Notice **example 2** and **3**. Best regard!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder re the article.@NayruLove. I have amended my answer accordingly. This now works in my example ... now to get it working on the real data! MAny thanks again!